# XPath expression unable to match

Tags: java, xpath

I'm trying to parse out some information from XML using XPath in Java (v 1.7). My XML looks like this:

```
<soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>code</faultcode>
    <faultstring>string</faultstring>
    <detail>detail</detail>
</soap:Fault>
```

My code:

```
final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlContent));
final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);

final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
final String faultCode = xPath.compile("/soap:Fault/faultcode/text()[1]").evaluate(document);
```

I have tried the XPath expression in an online checker with the XML content and it suggests that a match is made. However, when I run it in a wee stand-alone program, I get no value in "faultCode".

This issue is probably something simple, but I am unable to identify what the problem is.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I guess simply `/Fault/faultcode`. Try it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a namespace aware document builder factory:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Then you need a namespace context:

```
NamespaceContext nsContext = new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return "soap";
    }
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    }
};
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsContext);
```

With these additions, your code should work.

Regarding namespace contexts, I suggest you read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-nmspccontext/index.html.

Comment: Great - this is now working. With Michael's earlier reply and the addition of making the document builder factory namespace aware, the data is now correctly parsed from the XML using the XPath expression.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the namespace prefix "soap" to the URI "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" using the `XPath.setNamespaceContext()` method.

Comment: I have created a NamespaceContext object, overridden getNamespaceURI(), getPrefix() and getPrefixes() and added it to the xPath object but still get no match. The prefix is "soap" and the URI is "schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

Comment: This is now working. As well as a NamespaceContext class, I needed to make the DocumentBuilderFactory object namespace aware.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the namespaces effect. You can try namespace independent tags by matching with the local-name giving the syntax below:

```
   /*[local-name()='Fault' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']/*[local-name()='faultcode']/text()[1]
```

Comment: DId you see any change doing without namespaces?

Comment: Yes, this works - thank you. However, I'd like to use namespaces, as per the reply by Michael below.